# Android: Using Opencv Library for beginner (Conver to opencv format)

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, mat

i have a problem using opencv library on android. I try to convert imageview to bitmap, then convert bitmap to mat (for opencv process), and then i convert it again to bitmap. But i got force cloce when run the program. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final String TAG = null;
ImageView img;
Button btn;

private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
       switch (status) {
           case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
           {
          Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
          // Create and set View
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           } break;
           default:
           {
          super.onManagerConnected(status);
           } break;
       }
     }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LoaderCallbackInterface mLoaderCallback = null;
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6, this, mLoaderCallback);
}   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //convert imageview to bitmap
    img =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable();
    final Bitmap imgbitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //convert Bitmap to Mat
            Mat ImageMat = new Mat ( imgbitmap.getHeight(), imgbitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
            Bitmap myBitmap32 = imgbitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, ImageMat);

            //convert to grayscale
            Imgproc.cvtColor(ImageMat, ImageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,4);

            //Then convert the processed Mat to Bitmap
            Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ImageMat.cols(),  ImageMat.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);;
            Utils.matToBitmap(ImageMat, resultBitmap);


            //convert bitmap to imageview 
            ImageView imgbit;
            imgbit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imgbit.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
        }
    });        
}
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
12-09 16:27:23.052: D/dalvikvm(7837): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-09 16:27:23.582: D/dalvikvm(7837): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 50K, 45% free 3007K/5379K, external 733K/1041K, paused 359ms
12-09 16:27:23.762: D/InputQueue(7837): Registering input channel '2b3941f0 com.gozur.latihanpcd/com.gozur.latihanpcd.MainActivity (client)'
12-09 16:27:23.812: I/FihConfig(7837): can not find this tag <SYSTEM_CUST_HANDWRITING>in the mUsedConfigData Array
12-09 16:27:38.492: D/dalvikvm(7990): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 47K, 45% free 3007K/5379K, external 733K/1041K, paused 85ms
12-09 16:27:38.582: D/InputQueue(7990): Registering input channel '2b014008 com.gozur.latihanpcd/com.gozur.latihanpcd.MainActivity (client)'
12-09 16:27:38.642: I/FihConfig(7990): can not find this tag <SYSTEM_CUST_HANDWRITING>in the mUsedConfigData Array
12-09 16:27:40.362: D/WindowManager(7990): MotionEvent obtain 1 : MotionEvent{2afc4910 action=0 x=58.0 y=13.0 pressure=1.0 size=0.0}
12-09 16:27:40.492: W/dalvikvm(7990): No implementation found for native Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;.n_Mat (IIIDDDD)J
12-09 16:27:40.492: D/AndroidRuntime(7990): Shutting down VM
12-09 16:27:40.492: W/dalvikvm(7990): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc560)
12-09 16:27:40.502: E/AndroidRuntime(7990): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-09 16:27:40.532: W/System.err(7990): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/logcat_0.txt (Permission denied)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: n_Mat
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:535)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at com.gozur.latihanpcd.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:66)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2494)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9109)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
12-09 16:27:40.532: E/AndroidRuntime(7990):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 16:27:40.572: W/System.err(7990): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/plog.log (Permission denied)
```

Comment: post the logcat please.

Comment: @TharakaNirmana thats the logcat, thank you...

Comment: your native libs `link` is not correct, post some more code.

Comment: @Android-Developer ok, that my full code

Answer (score 3):

I pretty much doubt that your code can display the original version of your image before you are converting it to Grayscale since your log cat error says

```
 No implementation found for native Lorg/opencv/core/Mat
```

which means you have not done static initialization before calling opencv API

```
 static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) 
       {
        // Handle initialization error
    } }
```

Please follow the steps 3 and 4 from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html).

Comment: 404 for the link.Sorry but this is why people down vote for incomplete answers with link.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problems and it took me a day to understand. In your case try modifying your `onResume()` function to :

```
 @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_, this, mOpenCVCallBack);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mOpenCVCallBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);

        }
    }
```

I don't see a point in having this line:

```
 LoaderCallbackInterface mLoaderCallback = null;
```